# Two lists with related sizes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two public lists in my class.

I can change their sizes from inspector. I want their sizes depends on each other (when i change size of one second changes too), but I have no idea how to achieve it.

I tried to make my own class which inherits from list (that would let me call event on list rebuilding) and use it, but it dosn't display in inspector.

I tried to use [Serializable] to MyList, nothing changes.

Co You have any ideas how to do this?

```
 public class ListsTest : MonoBehaviour {

     public List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
     public List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

     public class MyList<T>: List<T>{

     }

     public MyList<string> list3 = new MyList<string>();
 }
```

[image]

**More complex example:**

Approach 1:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class ListTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public SomeData someData = new SomeData();

    public List<MoreData> moreData = new List<MoreData>();


    [Serializable]
    public class SomeData{
        public string data1;
        public string data2;
        //More data
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MoreData {

        public EvenMoreData evenMoreData = new EvenMoreData();
        public CanItGoAnyFurther canItGoAnyFurther = new CanItGoAnyFurther();

        [Serializable]
        public class EvenMoreData {
            public string data3;
            public string data4;
            //More data
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class CanItGoAnyFurther {
            public string data5;
            public string data6;
            //More data
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Approach 2:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class ListTest2 : MonoBehaviour {

    public SomeData someData = new SomeData();

    public List<EvenMoreData> evenMoreData = new List<EvenMoreData>();
    public List<CanItGoAnyFurther> canItGoAnyFurther = new List<CanItGoAnyFurther>();

    [Serializable]
    public class SomeData
    {
        public string data1;
        public string data2;
        //More data
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class EvenMoreData
    {
        public string data3;
        public string data4;
        //More data
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CanItGoAnyFurther
    {
        public string data5;
        public string data6;
        //More data
    }
}
```

[image]

In my opinion data in Approach 2 inspector is more readable and easier to compare for designer. But there is dwo list of independent sizes.

Comment: can you try changing the MyList definition to this : `public class MyList<T>: List<T>, IList<T> { }`

Comment: If these need to be "tied" to each other and have related content at each index, why not `List<Tuple<String, String>>` or a list of a class that has two strings? Then there is only one list to resize and the data stays together.

Comment: @crashmstr this is only a simple example. In my project I have several lists of classes with a lot of data (settings). I was thinking about your solution, and if I can't figure something else I propably do it that way. It depends on my teammates, what is more important to them - readability in inspector or easier resizable ;)

Comment: Well, if element 0 of each item is related to each other element 0 (and so on), then the data should normally be stored together as one "thing" instead of in parallel lists. If the elements don't relate, I'm not sure why you need to keep the lists the same size. You really don't give us enough information on real usage for this.

Comment: @Woltus, how are the lists linked together?  How will you know which elements to add and which to remove?

Comment: If you have multiple lists of different classes that have a 1:1 relationship with each other, then the correct approach really should be to use those separate classes as members of a single wrapper class, and have one list of that wrapper class.

Comment: I added a more complex example to my question.